# Is there any way of reindent the WHOLE code without using external codeblocks plugins?

Tags: linux, codeblocks, auto-indent

Is there any way to reindent the WHOLE CODE without installing the Smartindent plugin? A keyboard shortcut maybe?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to indent my code in codeblocks?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14707742/how-to-indent-my-code-in-codeblocks)

Comment: In retrospect I don't know if that is a dupe. That is about adding a tab to all lines I believe, not formatting it

Comment: What you're looking for isn't autoindent, you're looking for reindenting or code formatting.  CodeBlocks comes with that feature (AStyle).

Comment: @clcto I'm asking bc sometimes when copying a code from a pdf is really hard to reindent it manually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was select all code, then use the source code formatter plugin (AStyle) in the plugins button[image]

Answer (score -1):

In vi:

To insert a tab on every line:

:%s/^/\t/

Or if you wanted a certain number of spaces, replace \t with that.

Slightly more complex:

:%s/^([\t ])/\1\t/

Which says replace lines that begin with space or tab with that starting character plus a tab.  (You can substitute \t for number of spaces.)  This way, if your function definitions start in column 1, they'll still be there.  Additionally, blank lines will not unnecessarily have spaces/tabs inserted on them.

Comment: Thanks a lot Mark. That's an interesting solution. But I was just expecting to do it without coding a single line