# Remains second+ parameter line unaffected by AStyle

Tags: c++, astyle

I'm trying to formal my c++ code with AStyle utility and want to remain second line of function parametes unaffected by the tool. E.g. input file:

```
class C
{
public:
    void func(double d,
                 int i) const;
};

void C::func(double d,
                int i) const
{ }
```

After formatting with the following options:

```
--style=allman 
--pad-oper 
--pad-header 
--close-templates
--indent-switches 
--keep-one-line-blocks 
--keep-one-line-statements 
--unpad-paren 
--align-pointer=type 
--align-reference=type 
--mode=c
```

my file became as following:

```
class C
{
public:
    void func(double d,
              int i) const;
};

void C::func(double d,
             int i) const
{ }
```

I.e. `int i` is aligned same as `double d`.

Is there an option for AStyle to prevent formatting of the second (and more) line paramets of the function?

No metter is there a definition, a declaration or a call.

Comment: Do not use AStyle, it is an ancient tool with a lot of bugs and inconveniences, and it had its merit back at the time. Today there are much better tools, use clang-format.

Comment: @Yuki do you know a way to do what I need with clang-format?

Comment: You can use [Code::Blocks IDE](http://www.codeblocks.org/) with [AStyle plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14707742/how-to-indent-my-code-in-codeblocks/14711209), it allow you to edit the format style. If you don't want to use Code::Blocks it as IDE you can simply format the code, and continue using your preferred IDE

Comment: @alexolut, No I am not aware of any options that does what you want in clang-format. I think the way of aligning arguments like this is not common in the industry.

Comment: @Yuki but my desire is not to align at all. Just don't change start position of any parameter line.

Comment: @alexolut Neither alignment nor manual spacing between the type and the identifier is common. I really doubt that you find any formatter doing that. Though I know `uncrustify` tool that might be doing that, it has ridiculous amount of options (e.g. 700). Unfortunately, it is also badly supported, and outdated, I do not think that it even fully supports C++11. The best bet, imho, is to fork `clang-format` and introduce your own feature, that should not be so complicated, the code is quite readable.